# Remove code contracts in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: code-contracts, visual-studio-2017

My C# project developed in VS2015 used [Code Contracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/releases). This tool has gone stale since being open sourced by Microsoft and I don't plan to use it in VS2017. That said, when I attempt to run my project's unit tests in VS2017 it complains about the assembly needing to be rewritten using CCRewrite because it contains preconditions. When I create a new VS2017 project (as a test) with preconditions I do not get this error.

What do I need to do to get rid of the error message in my legacy project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found [another post](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/427) stating that `Contract.Requires<TException>(...)` requires a rewriter whereas `Contract.Requires(...)` does not. After making this change in my project it is now executing without errors in VS2017.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going nuts over why my tests do not run.